# how to read .dat file and grep specific value

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I am trying to read a .dat file using bash script.

The value contains file size I want to grep values bigger than 0 except first column. Greater than zero value can come in any row.

```
I have awk script to read line by line. 



 1349848860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349848920, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349848980, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349849040, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349849100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349849160, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 227.736, 2, 0, 29378, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349849220, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349849280, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349849340, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349851200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349851260, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349851320, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349851380, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 227.736, 2, 0, 29620, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349851440, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1

awk '{kount++;print  kount, $0}     END{print "\nTotal " kount " lines read"}' $FILENAME
awk '{print $13}' $FILENAME
```

Desired Output -

```
   227.736, 2,  29378 
   227.736, 2,  29620
```

Thanks for help.
Naveen

Comment: What is your questions? What values are you trying to grep?

Comment: This is not clear. Do you want to retrieve any positive integers after the first columns ? Display your expected output please.

Comment: Clear answers for an unclear question ;)

Comment: Where from hell this `644.982` value comes from ?

Comment: Sorry I messed up because ...values are changing frequently .....and I posted this question in hurry because urgent requirement. Extremely sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs :

```
awk -F"," '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){if ($i > 1) {print}}}' file.dat
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1349939700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 2, 0, 69832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 2, 0, 69832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 2, 0, 69832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 2, 0, 69832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 2, 0, 69832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 68552, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 68552, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 68552, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 68552, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349940000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 73826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349940000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 73826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349940000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 73826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349940000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 73826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to grep all the lines that contain a number other than 0 or 1, *not* counting the first number at the beginning of the line. How about

```
egrep ',.*([2-9]|[0-9.]{4,})' tmp.txt
```

This will print, from your example, the lines

```
1349939700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 2, 0, 69832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349939880, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 68552, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1349940000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14353, 1, 0, 450.03, 1, 0, 73826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the contents of every 13th (i.e 14353), 16th (i.e 450.03) and 19th (i.e 69832) column of each line (based on your input) in this file then try the following:

```
awk < test.dat -F ', ' '{print $13,$16,$19}'
```

where `test.dat` in your data file.

This will output:

```
14353 450.03 69832
0 0 0
0 0 0
14353 450.03 68552
0 0 0
14353 450.03 73826
```